# Publish to a Facebook Group as Page

Tags: facebook

I'm using the Facebook API to publish feeds on my own facebook group.
Until now, I can allow a group member to publish into the group, but I also want to publish feed as Page that manage the Group.

There is a way?

Thanks a lot for the answers!

Comment: Documentation only mentions posting using a user access token, so I am guessing no.